# How to access the last element of a xml file using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml object which is passed to a php variable called $var_PersonalStatus

```
<Statuses>
  <Status>
    <Name>Surviving Spouse</Name>
    <CreatedDate>2017-05-18</CreatedDate>
  </Status>
  <Status>
    <Name>Spouse</Name>
    <CreatedDate>2017-05-18</CreatedDate>
  </Status>
</Statuses>
```

if I print out the variable $var_PersonalStatus i get the whole xml like this:

```
Retiree2017-09-28Next of kin2017-09-28Retiree2017-09-28Employee2017-09-28
Deceased2017-09-28Next of Kin2017-09-28Retiree2017-09-28Spouse2017-09-282017-09-27
```

I want to be able to access the last node using PHP so that i can place just the last field "Name" in a select box. So far I been using this:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($var_PersonalStatus);
if ($var_PersonalStatus != '') {
  foreach($xml as $dta => $fd){
    $var_Ps = $fd->Name;
  }
}
```

but all i get is the first node name not the last one...
 Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problem can be solved by using xpath.

```
<?php
$var_PersonalStatus =<<<EOF
<Statuses>
  <Status>
    <Name>Surviving Spouse</Name>
    <CreatedDate>2017-05-18</CreatedDate>
  </Status>
  <Status>
    <Name>Spouse</Name>
    <CreatedDate>2017-05-18</CreatedDate>
  </Status>
</Statuses>
EOF;

$xml=simplexml_load_string($var_PersonalStatus); 

// TODO: Some sanity checks might be required here as the returned value of xpath could be empty.
$var_Ps=$xml->xpath('//Status[last()]/Name')[0];
```

Alternative xpath queries are:

- `(//Status[last()])/Name` to select the `Name` of the last `Status` element in the whole document.
- `/Statuses/Status[last()]/Name` to select the `Name` of the last `Status` which is a direct child of the root `Statuses` element.

Those alternatives become relevant, if a `Status` element can contain nested `Status` elements like in the following example.

```
<Statuses>
  <Status>
    <Name>Surviving Spouse</Name>
    <CreatedDate>2017-05-18</CreatedDate>
    <Statuses>
      <Status>
        <Name>Spouse</Name>
        <CreatedDate>2017-05-18</CreatedDate>
      </Status>
    </Statuses>
  </Status>
</Statuses>
```

Comment: Almost right. `//Status[last()]` selects every `Status` element that is the last `Status` child of its parent. If all the `Status` elements are siblings of each other, that's fine, but a closer fit to the stated requirement is `(//Status)[last()]` which selects the last `Status` element in the whole document.

Comment: @Corvus thank you for the answer but it is returning the first value entered by the user, I needed the last one, maybe I need to look for the first node in the xml object?

Comment: @ClaudioMartinez So by last you did not mean the last element in the xml document, but the one with the newest date, is that correct?

Comment: this worked for me `$xml = simplexml_load_string($var_PersonalStatus);
                
 $var_Ps= $xml->Status[0]->Name;`

Answer (score 0):

This will give you last element

```
<?php

$xml =new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); 
$var_Ps = "";
if($xmlstr != ''){
    foreach($xml as $dta => $fd){
        $var_Ps=$fd;
    }
}   
var_dump($var_Ps);
?>
```

Output will be :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
public 'Name' => string 'Spouse' (length=6)
public 'CreatedDate' => string '2017-05-18' (length=10)
```

Another way to get last element is:

```
$xml =new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$last = $xml->xpath("/Statuses/Status[last()]");
var_dump($last);
```

this will return following as output

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
  public 'Name' => string 'Spouse' (length=6)
  public 'CreatedDate' => string '2017-05-18' (length=10)
```